Bucle infinito, no veo el error C++
tengo que hacer un código donde tengo que factorizar un número en C++, por ejemplo factorizar 5 --> 5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120.  Entro en un bucle infinito, o me da cualquier resultado, ya me bloqueé.  La idea es ingresar números mientras yo le diga que si, y el número debe ser entero y positivo.  Si el número es 0, el resultado es 1.  Cuando le digo que no quiero factorizar más números, me tiene que mostrar el más alto y el más bajo.  Lo que hice es:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  //Variables
  int nro;
  int factor = 0;
  int factorizar = 0;
  int factormin = 0;
  int factormax = 0;
  //char continua;
  char continua = 's';


  //Ingreso de datos



do {
    cout <<"Desea ingresar un número entero positivo para factorizar  (s/S - n/N):  ";
    cin >> continua;
    
    cout <<"Ingrese el número a factorizar: ";
    cin >> nro;
    
    
    
    if(nro >= 0){
        //factorizar
        for (int i=1; i<=nro; i++){
            factorizar *= i;
        }
        
        
        //busca el máximo y el mínimo
        if (factorizar > factormax){
            factormax = factorizar;
        } else if (factorizar < factormin){
            factormin = factorizar;
        }
        
        
        //nostrar el resultado
        cout <<"El resultado de !"<< nro <<" es: " << factorizar << endl;
        
    } else if (nro == 0){
        cout << "El resultado de !0 es: 1" << endl;
        //return (0);
        }
        else
            cout << "Número inválido, intente nuevamente" << endl;
        
    
    
} while (continua == 's' || continua == 'S');

if (continua == 'n' || continua == 'N'){
     //mostrar maximo y minimo
     cout << "El número mas chico obtenido es: "<<factormin << endl;
     cout << "El número mas alto obtenido es: "<<factormax << endl;
} 


//mostrar maximo y minimo
//getch ();
return (0);
}

Si alguno puede ver donde está el error, se lo agradezco.
Muchas gracias!!

Me pregunto cual es el objetivo de factormax y factormin y su relación con el cálculo de factoriales.

Yo no veo ningún bucle infinito. Lo que si veo es que inicializaste la variable factorizar en 0.
Como sabemos, cualquier número por 0 da 0. Debes inicializarla en el neutro multiplicativo (1).
Por cierto, eso no es factorizar, es factorial y el signo de exclamación va después del número. A propósito, el factorial crece muy rápido así que int se quedará chico para números más grandes de 20. Considera usar double.

Es verdad, es factorial!!  Gracias por la aclaración, ahora me fijo.  Saludos!!
